# Change column order on a certain breakpoint

Tags: vuetify.js

I have 2 columns, and i want to change their orders on mobile from left to right, to right to left. Is this possible with vuetify, and how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

```
<template v-slot:item v-if="mobileBreakPoint">
<tr>
<td>{{item.item2}}</td>
<td>{{item.item1}}</td>
</tr>
</template>
```

Here's in the computed, to detect if the device is mobile or not

```
mobileBreakPoint() {
  if (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name == 'xs') {
      return true
  } else {
      return false
  }
}
```